# Kotlin: return map of async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'd like to return map of lazily-started coroutines and use them (start/cancel) in another function.

Problem is that getMap() function in following hangs. Why is that and is it possible to return such map from function?

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun getMap(): LinkedHashMap<String, Deferred<Any>> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        val map = linkedMapOf<String, Deferred<Any>>()
        map["1"] = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { 1 }
        map["2"] = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { 2 }
        map;
    }
}

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val map = getMap()
        println("not happening")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withContext` doesn't complete until all the coroutines launched within it complete. You can simplify your case to this:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            launch(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { 1 }
        }
        println("not happening")
    }
}
```

It doesn't complete either. The reason you got into this is that you used `withContext` inappropriately. Your `getMap()` has no reason to be a `suspend fun`.

What you need instead of `withContext` is setting a coroutine scope for these `async` calls. For example, this will work:

```
fun getMap(): Map<String, Deferred<Any>> =
        linkedMapOf<String, Deferred<Any>>().also { map ->
            with(GlobalScope) {
                map["1"] = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { 1 }
                map["2"] = async(start = CoroutineStart.LAZY) { 2 }
            }
        }

fun main() {
    val map = getMap()
    println("now it's happening")
}
```

Here you're using the global coroutine scope so you don't get any automatic cancellation. If you want to take care of that concern, replace it with something else.